# Does a Site Owner have Full Control for other Sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I have a Parent Site (Top Level Site) lets call Farm Logistics
There are several sub-sites:Pigs, Cattle, Chickens, and HR
There are 5 Site Admins for the Parent Site (Top Level Site) and sub sites.  I want to ensure that the Site Admins only have control for their respective sites.

When I created the sub-site and input the Site Owner (Site Admin) my understanding is this Site Owner/Site Admin has Full Control for the site, but what is not clear is if the Site Owner also has Full Control for all sites found within the Site Collection ?

My Site Owners will have limited SP experience and I essentially only want them to have the ability to add new members to their respective SP Permission Group that has been created for each team.

Comment: Site owner at top level site will have full control to subsites, unless subsites have explicitly broken inheriting permission from top and they have their own set of permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Site Collection Administrator have full control over site collection.
2. Site Owners (Full Control) have full control over the site on which access is provided.
3. If you have site owner at parent site and you don't want to share subsite with parent site owner:
   --> You can break the permission at subsite and then remove Parent Site Owner group and you can add Sub Site Owner group.
4. To have ability to add new members to their respective SP Permission group.
   --> You can manage SP Permission group by adding respective as Owner of SP Permission group.
   Site Action --> Site Setting --> People and Groups under Users and Permissions --> Groups ( will be available in left panel).

You can selected group and edit and input owner field. Then Owner will be able to add members to that group.

Hope this helps !!