# Sharepoint Item level Permission - Admin Access

Tags: list-item

We have applied the item level permission to each user so each user can see items that they created. As a admin, i want to see all the items.

How to control both users and admin in admin access.

Thanks
H

Comment: You can add yourself to SiteCollection administrator for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add admins to Site collection Administrator group. They will be able to see content for the site , even though the permission is break.

Explained different level of access [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165672/does-a-site-owner-have-full-control-for-other-sites/165673#165673)

Hope this helps!